# Dynamic Programming - Fibonacci - Performance of List better than Array

Tags: arrays, list, performance, haskell, optimization

I'm playing a little with Haskell and dynamic programming.

I have implemented a lot of problems, but in Fibonacci's case i'm getting some results that are PC dependants and i would like to confirm.

Assume the following implementations:

1)- List:

```
memoized_fib_list n = fibTab !! n
   where fibTab = map fibm [0 ..]
         fibm 0 = 0
         fibm 1 = 1
         fibm n = fibTab !! (n-2) + fibTab !! (n-1)
```

2)- Array:

```
memoized_fib_array n = fibTab ! n
  where fibTab = listArray (0, n) [mfib x | x <- [0..n]]
        mfib 0 = 0
        mfib 1 = 1
        mfib x = fibTab ! (x - 1) + fibTab ! (x - 2)
```

Result (with Criterion):

1. N = 15.000:
   List implementation: 171.5 μs
   Array implementation: 8.782 ms
2. N = 100.000:
   List implementation: 2.289 ms
   Array implementation: 195.7 ms
3. N = 130.000:
   List implementation: 3.708 ms
   Array implementation: 410.4 ms

The tests were run on a Notebook with a Core i7 Skylake, 8gb DDR4 and SSD (Ubuntu).

I was expecting the array implementation to be much better, and this was the only problem where the list implementation is better.

Could it be because of the sequential access? On some hardware with lower specs the list implementation has worse performance.

Note: I'm using the last (edit: latest) version of GHC.

Thanks.

---

Edit:

```
benchmark n = defaultMain [
    bgroup "fibonacci" [ 
                   bench "memoized_fib_list" $ whnf (memoized_fib_list) n
                 , bench "memoized_fib_array" $ whnf (memoized_fib_array) n
                 ]
                ]

main = do
{
    putStrLn "--------------EJECUTANDO BENCHMARK N=40------------------";
    benchmark 40;
    putStrLn "--------------EJECUTANDO BENCHMARK N=15000---------------";
    benchmark 15000;
    putStrLn "--------------EJECUTANDO BENCHMARK N=50000---------------";
    benchmark 50000;
    putStrLn "--------------EJECUTANDO BENCHMARK N=100000--------------";
    benchmark 100000;
    putStrLn "--------------EJECUTANDO BENCHMARK N=130000--------------";
    benchmark 130000;
}
```

---

Edit2: I installed Haskell Platform 8.2.2 on my windows 10 PC and got very similar results.

Intel i5 6600K, 16gb DDR4, SSD.

```
-------------------EJECUTANDO BENCHMARK N=130000------------------------
benchmarking best algo/memoized_fib_list
time                 1.818 ms   (1.774 ms .. 1.855 ms)
                     0.993 R²   (0.985 R² .. 0.998 R²)
mean                 1.853 ms   (1.826 ms .. 1.904 ms)
std dev              119.2 μs   (84.15 μs .. 191.3 μs)
variance introduced by outliers: 48% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking best algo/memoized_fib_array
time                 139.8 ms   (63.05 ms .. 221.8 ms)
                     0.884 R²   (0.623 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 287.0 ms   (221.4 ms .. 353.0 ms)
std dev              83.83 ms   (64.91 ms .. 101.6 ms)
variance introduced by outliers: 78% (severely inflated)
```

---

Edit3: Some additional information after running criterion with Linear Regression. All the values correspond to the execution with N = 130000.

-Number of garbage collections:

List implementation:

```
numGcs:              NaN R²     (NaN R² .. NaN R²)
  iters              0.000      (0.000 .. 0.000)
  y                  0.000      (0.000 .. 0.000)
```

Array Implementation:

```
numGcs:              1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
  iters              739.000    (739.000 .. 739.000)
  y                  2.040e-12  (-3.841e-12 .. 2.130e-12)
```

-Bytes allocated:

List implementation:

```
allocated:           0.001 R²   (0.000 R² .. 0.089 R²)
  iters              1.285      (-9.751 .. 13.730)
  y                  2344.014   (1748.809 .. 2995.439)
```

Array Implementation:

```
allocated:           1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
  iters              7.586e8    (7.586e8 .. 7.586e8)
  y                  1648.000   (1648.000 .. NaN)
```

-CPU cycles:

List implementation:

```
cycles:              0.992 R²   (0.984 R² .. 0.997 R²)
  iters              6759303.406 (6579945.392 .. 6962148.091)
  y                  -141047.582 (-4701325.840 .. 4674847.149)
```

Array Implementation:

```
cycles:              1.000 R²   (NaN R² .. 1.000 R²)
  iters              1.729e9    (1.680e9 .. 1.757e9)
  y                  -3311041.000 (NaN .. 6.513e7)
```

Comment: It's not useful to say you're using "the last version of GHC". I assume you meant "latest", as in newest, not the final version that will ever be published. But that is still not useful, because new versions are being released all the time, and your statement will soon stop being true. If you're going to mention a version, use a number that doesn't change.

Comment: Could not reproduce. On my machine, `memoized_fib_list 15000` takes ~1s while `memoized_fib_array 15000` takes ~0.009s. How are you testing this? Are you sure you're forcing the answer properly?

Comment: @amalloy sorry, yes, it's latest.

Comment: @DanielWagner i added how i'm running the tests.

Comment: @amalloy You are right. There is a new version 4 days old. I have versions 8.2.1 and 8.0.2 in my machines.

Comment: What options did you use to compile the code?

Comment: For those results the only flag is -O2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening here is quite simple: with `-O2`, GHC decides to make the memoisation-list in `memoized_fib_list` global.

```
$ ghc -fforce-recomp wtmpf-file4545.hs -O2 -ddump-prep

...

Main.memoizedFib_list :: GHC.Types.Int -> GHC.Integer.Type.Integer
[GblId, Arity=1, Str=<S(S),1*U(U)>, Unf=OtherCon []]
Main.memoizedFib_list
  = \ (n_sc61 [Occ=Once] :: GHC.Types.Int) ->
      GHC.List.!! @ GHC.Integer.Type.Integer Main.main_fibTab n_sc61

...

Main.main_fibTab :: [GHC.Integer.Type.Integer]
[GblId]
Main.main_fibTab
  = case Main.$wgo 0# of
    { (# ww1_sc5M [Occ=Once], ww2_sc5N [Occ=Once] #) ->
    GHC.Types.: @ GHC.Integer.Type.Integer ww1_sc5M ww2_sc5N
    }

...
```

That means, your criterion benchmark doesn't actually evaluate the fibonacci function repeatedly – it just performs repeated lookups in the same global list. And averaged over many evaluations, this gives a very good score, which is however not representative of how fast the *calculation* is.

GHC performs this optimisation in the list implementation because you don't need lists of different length – it's always an infinite list of *all* Fibonacci number. That's not possible in the array implementation, so this can't keep up here.

The simples way to prevent this globalisation would be to make `fibm` explicitly dependent on `n`, by just trimming it to the needed finite lenght like the arrays are as well.

```
memoizedFib_list :: Int -> Integer
memoizedFib_list n = fibTab !! n
   where fibTab = map fibm [0 ..]
         fibm 0 = 0
         fibm 1 = 1
         fibm n = fibTab !! (n-2) + fibTab !! (n-1)
```

With this, the list implementation becomes much slower than the array one, as one would expect seeing memo-lookup is *O*(*n*) for lists:

```
$ ghc -fforce-recomp wtmpf-file4545.hs -O2 && ./wtmpf-file4545 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( wtmpf-file4545.hs, wtmpf-file4545.o )
Linking wtmpf-file4545 ...
--------------EJECUTANDO BENCHMARK N=40------------------
benchmarking fibonacci/memoizedFib_list
time                 10.47 μs   (10.42 μs .. 10.51 μs)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 10.40 μs   (10.35 μs .. 10.44 μs)
std dev              163.3 ns   (122.2 ns .. 225.8 ns)
variance introduced by outliers: 13% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking fibonacci/memoizedFib_array
time                 1.618 μs   (1.617 μs .. 1.620 μs)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 1.620 μs   (1.618 μs .. 1.623 μs)
std dev              7.521 ns   (4.079 ns .. 12.48 ns)

benchmarking fibonacci/memoizedFib_vector
time                 1.573 μs   (1.572 μs .. 1.574 μs)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 1.572 μs   (1.571 μs .. 1.573 μs)
std dev              2.351 ns   (1.417 ns .. 4.040 ns)

--------------EJECUTANDO BENCHMARK N=1500----------------
benchmarking fibonacci/memoizedFib_list
time                 18.52 ms   (18.41 ms .. 18.68 ms)
                     1.000 R²   (0.999 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 18.65 ms   (18.53 ms .. 18.84 ms)
std dev              355.1 μs   (204.8 μs .. 592.1 μs)

benchmarking fibonacci/memoizedFib_array
time                 135.2 μs   (131.2 μs .. 140.1 μs)
                     0.996 R²   (0.991 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 132.7 μs   (131.9 μs .. 135.0 μs)
std dev              4.463 μs   (2.024 μs .. 8.327 μs)
variance introduced by outliers: 32% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking fibonacci/memoizedFib_vector
time                 131.8 μs   (130.6 μs .. 133.2 μs)
                     0.999 R²   (0.999 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 132.5 μs   (131.4 μs .. 134.1 μs)
std dev              4.383 μs   (3.463 μs .. 5.952 μs)
variance introduced by outliers: 31% (moderately inflated)
```

[`Vector`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.1/docs/Data-Vector.html) which I also tested here performs yet a bit faster, but not really significantly. I think as soon as you use a container with *O*(1) lookup, the performance is dominated by the additions of the pretty huge numbers, so you're really benchmarking GMP rather than anything Haskell has to do with.

```
import qualified Data.Vector as V

memoizedFib_vector :: Int -> Integer
memoizedFib_vector n = fibTab V.! n
  where fibTab = V.generate (n+1) mfib
        mfib 0 = 0
        mfib 1 = 1
        mfib x = fibTab V.! (x - 1) + fibTab V.! (x - 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That explains a lot.

Comment: I also made tests using Vectors (both with safe and unsafe access and creation) but the improvement wasn't significative. I also used some other data structures and the best result where obtained using Tries. But as a newbie in haskell i found the list vs array counterintuitive and puzzling.

Comment: @SergioDanielCoronelMalvarez well, Haskell is very good at lists. And the ability to make them infinite is really useful, this being a straightforward example. Generally, I would stick to purely functional data structures unless it's clear that an array is needed (and this actually makes most sense when you can make it an _unboxed_ array, which isn't possible with `Integer`).